# Google Authentication API not refreshing after a couple d

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I followed the google API authentication steps, it worked initially but after a couple days following the same steps and redownloading "secrets" give me the above error, I thought this flow was supposed to refresh the Google API token or am I missing something?

```
def main():
    global credentials
    credentials = None
    client_secrets_path = r"C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Code/Code/credentials.json" 
    if os.path.exists("token.json"):
        credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_path, SCOPES)
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open("token.json", "w") as token:
            token.write(credentials.to_json())
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: why do you redownloaded "secrets" ? If you use new "secret" then you should delete old token, and it will need new authorization.

Comment: - furas, I tried to do that but it kept giving me an error saying there was code and even when I cntrl-K it would give me the same error. I wasn't able to fix that unfortunately. As for redownloading, that's been the only way I've fixed it in the past, I've had to do this multiple times. It use to work without doing that and just asking to "sign in" from my Google account again but it stopped doing that a couple months back with the same code snipet. Idk what changed.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh tokens expire after seven days if you're app is in testing.

Once you are done testing go to the consent screen on Google console for your project and click the button to put it into production

You will need to delete token.json to force your code to request authorization again